# how do i add a newline after each item in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of some characters. When I print it I get the following output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

But what I want is this:

```
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e']
```

I have tried .join but that removes the [] and the '' and I dont want that.

Any help appreciated. I have tried to search but I can only find .join solutions.

Thanks

Edit: is it possible to return the list this way also? or just print it like that?

Comment: "is it possible to return the list this way also? or just print it like that?" <- There is zero difference between the two lists. All you are changing is how you display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an hackish way to do it with `print` in Python 3:

```
>>> print(*str(lst).split(','), sep=',\n')
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e']
```

Comment: this worked but i need to return the list in that state instead of just printing it. is that possible ?

Comment: @JensB How do mean *return the list in that state*? There you have a string, not a list. Calling print on a list gives you a string showing the items in the list with the square braces as identifiers. The list remains the same, irrespective of how it's printed.

Comment: nevermind, your solution worked. i was misunderstanding a bit. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) ("pretty-print") module:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], width=1)
```

If you want to get the value as a string instead of printing it, use `pformat` instead of `pprint`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `str.replace()` approach:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(repr(lst).replace(',', ',\n'))
```

The output:

```
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way:

```
>>> ok = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for x in ok.__repr__().split():
>>>     print(x)
...
... 
['a',
'b',
'c',
'd',
'e']

# py2
# for x in ok.__str__().split():print(x)
```